# ActionCable Issue with if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am transmitting Messages via ActionCable and I got this in the messages-partial:

```
- if current_user.admin?
  = link_to "[x]", msg_path(msg), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "sure?"}
```

If a normal user sends a message this works fine, but when an administrator sends one, the other normal users get the link displayed, but when I refresh the page it disapeared.

How to prenvent this?

Comment: can you show the .admin? method?

Comment: It's just an attribute of `user`. If it's true, then the user is admin.

Comment: are you sure the code is not duplicated? change link_to "[x]" ,  to  link_to "TEST", to see if normal users see the new text

Comment: I'm sure because when I refresh the page, the link is gone

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely broadcasting the message to everyone. You need to implement something like this inside of your message controller, so that only subscribers to that channel receive it (messages_controller.rb):

```
def delete
  if message.destroy
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "messages_#{message.chatroom_id}_channel",
      message_id: message.id
    head :ok
  end
end
```

Similarly, you need to subscribe to the the proper channel (messages_channel.rb):

```
def subscribed
  stream_from "messages_#{params['chatroom_id']}_channel"
end
```

Comment: I did exactly the same